# Diffferential Equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I have an equation:
$$f''''(x) = f'''(x) \frac{\partial H}{\partial y'''} + f''(x) \frac{\partial H}{\partial y''}.$$
How can I solve this equation for $H$, where $H$ is a function of $x, y'', and \ \ y''' \ \ and \ \ f''$ is non - zero.
Any help or hints will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Is $f(x)$ supposed to be equal to $y$?

Comment: No f is any function of x.

Answer (score 2):

Method of characteristics will definitely work. Also the standard Ansatz for transport equations will work and  both yield:
$$
H(x,y'',y''')=G\Big(y''f'''(x)-y'''f''(x),x\Big)+y''\tfrac{f''''(x)}{f''(x)}
$$
For any function $G$ smooth enough. Notice that the variable $x$ is only a parameter here, if you meant something different please clarify in the OP. Similarly, $y''$ and $y'''$ are treated as variables not as functions.

Comment: Thanks. You are right.